# Correct usage of typeof in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS.

Here is the sample example I am experimenting on:

My little program just prints the all the language name(notALanguage is ignored ).

**First program:**

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

// print hello in the 3 different languages;

for(var i in languages)
{
    if(typeof languages[i] === "string")
    console.log(languages[i]);
}
```

**output:**

```
Hello!
Bonjour!
Hola!
```

which is correct.

Initially I have written the above code using .(DOT) operator in the for loop.

**Second Program:**

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

// print hello in the 3 different languages;

for(var i in languages)
{
    if(typeof languages.i === "string")
    console.log(languages.i);
}
```

The second program could not print anything(why?).

So I have added few output statements before the if statement in the forloop to get to know the value of i,language.i anf typeof language.i;

so the modified second program looks like this:

**Modified Second Program:**

```
var languages = {
    english: "Hello!",
    french: "Bonjour!",
    notALanguage: 4,
    spanish: "Hola!"
};

// print hello in the 3 different languages;

for(var i in languages)
{
    console.log("i = " + i);
    console.log("languages.i = "+languages.i);
    console.log("typeof languages.i = "+ typeof languages.i);
    //console.log(typeof languages.i);
    if(typeof languages.i === "string")
    console.log(languages[i]);
}
```

and the output looks like this:

**Output:**

```
i = english
languages.i = undefined
typeof languages.i = undefined
i = french
languages.i = undefined
typeof languages.i = undefined
i = notALanguage
languages.i = undefined
typeof languages.i = undefined
i = spanish
languages.i = undefined
typeof languages.i = undefined
```

Why is languages.i not able to pick up right reference when the value of i is perfect?

Why is that only languages[i] working?

What are the differences between two notations languages.i and languages[i] and what to use where?

Comment: Because your `languages` object doesn't look like `{i: "some odd language"}`. The other ones are accessible as `languages.english`, `languages.notALanguage` and so on, but there is not `languages.i` so it yields `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a property name is dynamic, you must use the bracket notation to access it. `languages.i` is basically `languages['i']`.